# Azure Devops Restore SQL Database as part of my release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

In my release pipeline to my Integration Environment I want to restore the production database prior running the migration script.

Both my databases are hosted in Azure. So I thought I could use the `Azure SQL Database Deployment` task that is already integrated to the Azure Dedvops. I created two separate tasks. First Export to a `.bacpac` file and then import that `.bacpac` file again. Currently I am running into the following issue:

```
...
2018-11-22T09:02:28.9173416Z Processing Table '[dbo].[EmergencyContacts]'.
2018-11-22T09:02:31.6364073Z Successfully exported database and saved it to file 'D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\DatabaseName.bacpac'.
2018-11-22T09:02:31.6726957Z Generated file D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\DatabaseName.bacpac. Uploading file to the logs.

2018-11-22T09:02:31.6798180Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.uploadfile] D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\DatabaseName.bacpac' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2018-11-22T09:02:31.6812314Z ##[error]Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file not exist on disk

2018-11-22T09:02:31.7016975Z Setting output variable 'SqlDeploymentOutputFile' to 'D:\a\r1\a\GeneratedOutputFiles\DatabaseName.bacpac'
2018-11-22T09:02:31.7479327Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure SQL Export`enter code here`
```

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you manage to resolve?